# Waveshare 7" DPI + RPi Zero W - display not working

Tags: pi-zero, display, screen, hat

I have obtained this display:
https://www.waveshare.com/7inch-lcd-for-pi.htm

and followed instructions here for Bullseye: https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7inch_LCD_for_Pi

I have copied overlay files into /boot/overlays/.

I have RPi Zero W connected to display via RGB Hat. If I turn on the switch for backlight, that works. However nothing seems to be displayed ever (blank screen).

Scroll to **update** below.

My /boot/config.txt:

I have tried using option 1:

```
[all]
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-DPI-7inch
dtoverlay=waveshare-7dpi
```

I have tried also using option 2:

```
dtoverlay=dpi24
enable_dpi_lcd=1
display_default_lcd=1
dpi_group=2
dpi_mode=87
dpi_output_format=0x6f005
hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
disable_overscan=1
```

(while commenting out the option 1 lines)

I have even added this:

`dpi_timings=1024 1 40 48 128 600 1 13 3 45 0 0 0 60 0 37000000 6`

Further logs on enabling `dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d`:

```
$ sudo kmsprint
Connector 0 (32) HDMI-A-1 (disconnected)
Encoder 0 (31) TMDS

$ raspi-gpio get
BANK0 (GPIO 0 to 27):
GPIO 0: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 1: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 2: level=1 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SDA1
GPIO 3: level=1 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SCL1
GPIO 4: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 5: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 6: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 7: level=1 fsel=1 func=OUTPUT
GPIO 8: level=1 fsel=1 func=OUTPUT
GPIO 9: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SPI0_MISO
GPIO 10: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SPI0_MOSI
GPIO 11: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SPI0_SCLK
GPIO 12: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 13: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 14: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 15: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 16: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 17: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 18: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=PCM_CLK
GPIO 19: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=PCM_FS
GPIO 20: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=PCM_DIN
GPIO 21: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=PCM_DOUT
GPIO 22: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 23: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 24: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 25: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 26: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 27: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
BANK1 (GPIO 28 to 45):
GPIO 28: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 29: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 30: level=0 fsel=7 alt=3 func=CTS0
GPIO 31: level=0 fsel=7 alt=3 func=RTS0
GPIO 32: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=TXD0
GPIO 33: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=RXD0
GPIO 34: level=0 fsel=7 alt=3 func=SD1_CLK
GPIO 35: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=SD1_CMD
GPIO 36: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=SD1_DAT0
GPIO 37: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=SD1_DAT1
GPIO 38: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=SD1_DAT2
GPIO 39: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=SD1_DAT3
GPIO 40: level=0 fsel=1 func=OUTPUT
GPIO 41: level=1 fsel=1 func=OUTPUT
GPIO 42: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 43: level=1 fsel=4 alt=0 func=GPCLK2
GPIO 44: level=0 fsel=1 func=OUTPUT
GPIO 45: level=1 fsel=1 func=OUTPUT
BANK2 (GPIO 46 to 53):
GPIO 46: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT
GPIO 47: level=0 fsel=1 func=OUTPUT
GPIO 48: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SD0_CLK
GPIO 49: level=1 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SD0_CMD
GPIO 50: level=1 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SD0_DAT0
GPIO 51: level=1 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SD0_DAT1
GPIO 52: level=1 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SD0_DAT2
GPIO 53: level=1 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SD0_DAT3
```

I have uncommented in /boot/config.txt:

```
# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=on
```

Still no output, screen blank, backlight working (if turned on via a switch).

**UPDATE**
Thanks for chipping in, guys.

I am getting this:

```
$ kmsprint
Connector 0 (32) HDMI-A-1 (disconnected)
Encoder 0 (31) TMDS
Connector 1 (42) DPI-1 (connected)
Encoder 1 (41) DPI
Crtc 1 (71) 1024x600@38.37 29.500 1024/40/48/128/+ 600/13/3/4/+ 38 (38.37)
Plane 1 (61) fb-id: 297 (crtcs: 1) 0,0 1024x600 -> 0,0 1024x600 (XR24 AR24 AB24 XB24 RG16 BG16 AR15 XR15 RG24 BG24 YU16 YV16 YU24 YV24 YU12 YV12 NV12 NV21 NV16 NV61 RGB8 BGR8 XR12 AR12 XB12 AB12 BX12 BA12 RX12 RA12)
FB 297 1024x600 XR24
Plane 21 (264) fb-id: 299 (crtcs: 1) 0,0 64x64 -> 501,288 64x64 (XR24 AR24 AB24 XB24 RG16 BG16 AR15 XR15 RG24 BG24 YU16 YV16 YU24 YV24 YU12 YV12 NV12 NV21 NV16 NV61 RGB8 BGR8 XR12 AR12 XB12 AB12 BX12 BA12 RX12 RA12)
FB 299 64x64 AR24
```

with this /boot/config.txt:

```
[pi4]
# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1
dpi_timings=1024 1 40 48 128 600 1 13 3 45 0 0 0 60 0 37000000 6

[all]
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
#dtoverlay=vc4-kms-DPI-7inch
#dtoverlay=waveshare-7dpi
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-dpi-generic,hactive=1024,hfp=40,hsync=48,hbp=128,vactive=600,vfp=13,vsync=3,vbp=45,clock-frequency=37000000,rgb66
#dtparam=rotate=90
```

But still no image on the Waveshare LCD. If I run xrandr --query, I only get this however:

```
$ xrandr --query
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
1920x1080     60.01 +
1680x1050     60.01
1280x1024     60.01
1440x900      60.01
1280x800      60.01
1280x720      60.01
1024x768      60.01
800x600       60.01
640x480       60.01
HDMI-A-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94
1600x1200     60.00
1680x1050     59.88
1280x1024     60.02
1440x900      59.90
1280x960      60.00
1280x800      59.91
1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
1024x768      60.00
800x600       60.32    56.25
720x576       50.00
720x480       60.00    59.94
640x480       60.00    59.94
```

Any further help appreciated.

Comment: Please check your power supply. Sometimes displays might not work properly if the power supply is insufficient. Also, confirm that the display you have is compatible with the Raspberry Pi Zero W. Some displays might require specific configurations or might not be compatible with certain models of Raspberry Pi.

Comment: The website states Pi Zero is supported. The power supply is one provided by RPi shop. 5V, 2A, standard.

Comment: Have you contacted waveshare customer care regarding this matter?

Comment: Sure.Sure.Sure.